# How to remove all type of nan from the dataframe.?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, nan

I had a data frame, which is shown below. I want to merge column values into one column, excluding nan values.

Image 1:

[image]

When I am using the code

```
df3["Generation"] = df3[df3.columns[5:]].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.dropna()), axis=1)
```

I am getting results like this.

Image 2:

[image]

Comment: What is the nature of your data? Could you post the [minimal data sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), please.

Comment: Please provide sample data

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that these columns are of type string; thus, they are not affected by `x.dropna()`.

One example that I made is this, which gives similar results as yours.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [np.nan, np.nan, 1, 2], 'b': [1, 1, np.nan, None]}).astype(str)
df.apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.dropna()))

0    nan,1.0
1    nan,1.0
2    1.0,nan
3    2.0,nan
dtype: object

-----------------
# using simple string comparing solves the problem
df.apply(lambda x: ','.join(x[x!='nan']), axis=1)

0    1.0
1    1.0
2    1.0
3    2.0
dtype: object
```